# Escrow Payment Processing Solution Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, payment-processing, escrow

I'm working on a Marketplace project and I am looking for a simple payment solution that would facilitate transactions made between Buyers and Sellers globally.

There will have to be an Escrow system and the payments would go through only after the job has been marked complete.

Please suggest RubyGems to perform this functionality. External built API's with comprehensive documentation will also be appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to look at this @zeeshan? https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/guides/marketplace/create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented escrow payment management using gem [braintree_ruby](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby). A ruby quick [example](http://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby) is very helpful as recommended by "@Sannan" in comments.  Full project with Rails integration is located [here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby_examples) on github.